# Pass char** as an argument to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort

I know there are many topics of this kind but I've read several of them and still can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

I've successfully generated a char** array. My bubble sort function probably works as well. But when I passed the generated array to the function, only 1 row is copied.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

void sort(char** tab)
{
        char* temp;
        int i, j, size = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);
        printf("%d\n", size);

        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
                for(j = i+1; j < size; ++j)
                {
                        if(strcmp(tab[j-1], tab[j]) > 0)
                                strcpy(temp, tab[j-1]),
                                strcpy(tab[j-1], tab[j]),
                                strcpy(tab[j], temp);
                }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]); ++i)
                puts(tab[i]);
}

int main()
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        int size = rand()%5+5, i, j, s;
        char** tab = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char*));

        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
                s = rand()%9+1;
                tab[i] = (char*)malloc(s+1);
                for(j = 0; j < s; ++j)
                        tab[i][j] = 'a'+rand()%26;
                tab[i][s] = 0;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                puts(tab[i]);
        puts("");
        sort(tab);
        return 0;
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/xVqIKV)'s how the code works.

And when I write size=5 before the loop in the function it returns segmentation fault.

**Edit:** Same with passing the size of the array as an argument:
http://ideone.com/3Wvncq

### Final code

I've fixed all the problems and here's the [final code](http://ideone.com/xwC6g2).
I was misinterpreting segmentation fault as the result of assigning a fixed size instead of not allocating the temp variable.
Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: 1) Follow ameyCU's advice about passing "size" as a parameter (instead of trying to compute it inside the function.  2) Allocate space for "temp" (don't "strcpy()" into a pointer!!!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't calculate size inside function `void sort(char** tab)` . As in this function it will be calculated as -

```
int i, j, size = sizeof(tab)/sizeof(tab[0]);   // equivalent to sizeof(char **)/sizeof(char*) in function giving wrong length as you desire.
```

It's length in `main`(`size` is generated using `rand` so no need to find it) and then pass it as argument to function `sort`.

Declare your function like this -

```
void sort(char** tab,size_t size)
```

And while calling from main pass length of `tab` to it -

```
sort(tab,size);  // size will be number of elements in tab calculated in main
```

You get **segmentation fault** because of this -

```
    if(strcmp(tab[j-1], tab[j]) > 0)
                 strcpy(temp, tab[j-1]),         
                 strcpy(tab[j-1], tab[j]),       
                 strcpy(tab[j], temp);
```

`temp` is **uninitialized** in `sort` and still you pass it to `strcpy` thus **undefined behaviour** . *Initialize* `temp` before passing to `strcpy`.Allocate memory to `temp` in function `sort`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning *why* the OP shouldn't calculate inside the function.

Comment: I've tried that and it works as just assigning size=5 (5 being the minimal size). It returns segmentation fault as well. Please see: http://ideone.com/3Wvncq

Comment: @ameyCU, `tab` is a malloc(ated) pointer (not an array)  in `main`, you can't get the size with `sizeof` in this case.

Comment: @mr_jigsaw  I have added reason for segmentation fault.

Comment: @AlterMann Yes , that's why I have added to calculate its length not size . In `main` it is generated using `rand` so no need to explicitly find it .

Comment: If the `// missing ;` get fixed won't `{`curly braces`}` also be needed...?

Comment: @CharlieScott-Skinner  I guess not . `;` will also not be required I think . it compile good .

Comment: @ameyCU, ah, ok, "Calculate it's length" was confusing me since `size` is already calculated using `rand`.

Comment: @AlterMann Sorry , for such explanation .I mentioned it in answer .

Answer (score 1):

In your `sort` function you declare the `temp` variable:

```
char* temp;
```

Later you use it as destination (and source) for string copying:

```
strcpy(temp, tab[j-1]),
```

But nowhere in between do you make `temp` point anywhere, `temp` is uninitialized and that leads to *undefined behavior* and your crash.

Don't use a pointer, instead declare it as an array of the largest string size possible.